# Is it possible to remove next-post / previous-post with out creating a custom template?

Tags: plugin-development, filters, the-content, previous-post-link

I'm creating a plugin that uses a custom post type. I do not want to make a custom template for viewing the posts and discovered I can add a filter for the_content to include my custom fields, this works great. However, I don't want visitors to navigate the custom post types with the previous next navigation. It there a way to remove these without creating a custom template?

Thank you for taking the time to look at my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function remove_link( $format, $link ) {
    return false;
}
add_filter( 'previous_post_link', 'remove_link' );
add_filter( 'next_post_link', 'remove_link' );
```

It should work if the theme uses `next_post_link()` and `previous_post_link()`.

Cheers

Comment: Darko, Thank you, looks like your memory is a was a little hazy but I was able to sort it out. Here's what I wound up with and it's seams to solve my issue. (Can't figure out how to enter returns in comments, sorry for the lack of formatting...):  function remove_link( $format ) {
    return false;
}
add_filter( 'previous_post_link', 'remove_link' );
add_filter( 'next_post_link', 'remove_link' );

Comment: Oh oh, sorry about that! Will fix it, but glad you got it working.

Comment: How do you make this work only for certain post types?

Comment: I have tested this code snippet on Twenty Twenty and it doesn't remove the previous / next post links... Any idea?